# Gson - nice serialisation of Kotlin enums with a value

Tags: json, serialization, kotlin, gson

I have an enum with values

```
enum class Foo(val serverVal:Int) {
     BAR(1),
     BUG(2)
}
```

that I would like to use with a class:

```
data class C1(val fooVal:Foo)
```

I want to be able to serialise it with a code that looks as close as can be to:

```
Gson().toJson(C1(Foo.BAR))
```

That would yield

```
{"fooVal":1}
```

Instead of the default conversion, which is, of course `{"fooVal":"BAR"}`. If it was a string value I could have used `@SerializedName`, but I can't because it's an Int, not a String.

Is there a simple way to add something to Foo, in order to show Gson how to take the Int value from Foo entries rather than their name?

Examples I saw in Java include EnumAdapterFactory and TypeAdapter which are quite cumbersome and defeat the purpose of a pretty code.

I would love to get a solution that is maintained inside the data structure.

```
enum class SomeEnum(val i:Int) {
   V1(1), V2(10), V3(5);

companion object {
   @SerializeMeLikeThis
   fun toJson() = i;

   @DeserializeMeLikeThat
   fun fromJson(v:Int) = values().find{it.i == v}?:whatever
}
}
```

An ugly way but still encapsulated-ish

```
data class C2(@SerializedName("foo") var serverFoo:Int) {
    // Becomes a nightmare with many params.
    constructor(f:Foo) : this(F.serverVal)
    var foo:Foo 
      get() = Foo.values().find{serverFoo == it.serverVal}?:whatever
      set(v) { serverFoo = v.serverVal }
}
```

So it can be called

```
Gson().toJson(C2(BAR))
```

and

```
// Result: Foo.BAR
Gson().fromJson("""{"foo":"1"}""", C2::class.java).foo
```

Well, you can live on it...but it... :-(

Any nice way?

Thanks

Comment: Ugly solution: Make the field an Int and add a secondary constructor to convert things: `constructor(foo:Foo): this(foo.serverVal)`. It is fair for tiny data structures, but it becomes a real nuisance when your class has 5 or more members.

Comment: Why not `gson.toJson(C1(Foo.BAR))`? Just make a top-level val and register the type adapter there.

Comment: Thanks. I preferred to avoid TypeAdapter because it's pretty cumbersome. It is pretty large, and some of it is outside my object... I will need to `Gson().registerTypeAdapter(object:TypeAdapter<Foo>() { read... write...}).toJson()`
Actually, I can't even encapsulate it at the enum to separate it from the outside world and make it the enum's "private business". Is there a similar trick with annotations? Or methods inside the enum (like "toJson" meaning "this is how you make a JSON out of me")?

Comment: "I will need to `Gson().registerTypeAdapter(object:TypeAdapter<Foo>() { read... write...}).toJson()`" As I said, no you don't. Just create a single Gson instance and use it everywhere instead of calling `registerTypeAdapter` every time.

Comment: This doesn't directly encapsulate, but you can use https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html instead if you want that. After writing a superclass once, it should be two lines of code per enum. This should also allow `Gson().toJson(C1(Foo.BAR))` if you really to create an instance every time (but why?)

Comment: Thanks. I might have misunderstood but I would rather keep the data structure as a black box. I would rather avoid parser codes that knows how to parse particular members in the data structure. I would rather keep the knowledge in the datastruct and have the code that refers to it simple. With TypeAdapter I will need to define it in the code that handles the datastruct, it's gonna be a specific TypeAdapter for each enum member of the datastruct. I have to do it only once but it's a pity because I touch that datastruct only in one place. Defeats the purpose.